# How to pass output of 1 scenario to 2nd scenario as input

Tags: cucumber

For the below scenarios, I want to use the **output of @login** as **input for @logout**...

Note- I have made **2 different step definitions** for login and logout

@login
Scenario Outline: Login
Given Browser
And Link
When Enter <username> and <password>
When Enter Captcha
When Check Privacy Policy
And Click on Login

```
Examples: 
  | username   | password | 
  | 2100070100 | 12345678 |
```

@logout
Scenario: Logout
Then Once Successful Login, Click Logout
Then Close The Browser

After successful login using valid login credentials, I want to click logout...

Comment: Why don't you just join these two scenarios? Making scenarios dependent is antipattern

Comment: If i join them it will make very complex code

Answer (score 0):

You cannot (and should not try to) pass the output of one scenario to another. The whole point of a scenario is to be an independent test that works in isolation.

You should write at least two scenarios

```
Scenario: I login

Scenario: I logout
```

The first scenario should be something like

```
Scenario: Login
  Given I am registered
  When I login
  Then I should be logged in
```

The second scenario should be something like

```
Scenario: I logout
  Given I am logged in
  When I log out
  Then I should be logged out
```

Now you can resume the code in `When I login` in `Given I am logged in`

Here is what I would do in a bit more detail in Rubyish pseudocode

```
module LoginStepHelper
  def login_as(user: )
    # code to login
    visit login_path
    fill_in 'username', user.username
    fill_in 'password', user.password
    submit_form
  end
  def logout
    click_link 'Logout'
  end
end
World LoginStepHelper

When 'I login' do
  login_as(user: @i)
end

Given 'I am logged in' do
  login_as(user: @i)
end
...
```